# SignalR Client Not Receiving Notification when using jquery 3.3.1

Tags: jquery, signalr

I am sending notification using

```
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyMonitoringHub>()
         .Clients.All.sendupdate("Test")
```

When using jquery-1.6.4.min.js on the html listener, I get the notifications. But when using jquery-3.3.1.js, there is  no notification.

I'm using "jquery.signalR-2.4.2.js"

Client side, I am using as below:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var monitorBroadCast = monitorHubConnection.createHubProxy('MyMonitoringHub');

    monitorBroadCast.on("sendupdate", function (message) {
       alert("Notified");
    });

    monitorHubConnection.start().done(function () {
       $("#status").text("").prepend("<i>sendupdate</i> event is being listened 
               !").prepend("Connected. ").css("color", "green");
        }).fail(function (reason) {
            $("#status").text("").prepend("<i>sendupdate</i> event listening failed 
               !").prepend("Disconnected. ").css("color", "green")
        });
    });
```

Comment: Any updates from anyone?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have your connection object defined (monitorHubConnection).

[Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client) -

```
var connection = $.hubConnection(); // This is what it appears you are missing.
var contosoChatHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('contosoChatHub');
contosoChatHubProxy.on('addContosoChatMessageToPage', function(name, message) {
    console.log(name + ' ' + message);
});
connection.start().done(function() {
    // Wire up Send button to call NewContosoChatMessage on the server.
    $('#newContosoChatMessage').click(function () {
        contosoChatHubProxy.invoke('newContosoChatMessage', $('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
        $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
    });
```